# How can I send raw IP packets with Perl under Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, network-programming, network-protocols

Is there any Perl module which has the capability to send raw packets on Windows?
I know there is `Net::RawIP`, but it seems that it does not work on Windows.

Comment: I think I remember reading something about Microsoft removing the ability to send raw packets.

Comment: @Brad Correct, after Steve Gibson made a huge stink about it, MS disabled raw socket support in XP SP2.  The original page is no longer available, but you can find many references to it: http://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.GRC.com%2Fdos%2Fwinxp.htm

Comment: This is the original Steve Gibson's text: http://web.archive.org/web/20071128030853/http://www.grc.com:80/dos/winxp.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Net::Write](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Write)?

Answer (score 2):

On XPSP2/3, you need to use something like WinPCap, it can create raw ethernet packets for you