# How can I capture and edit network packets on the fly with Perl?

Tags: perl, network-programming, network-protocols, libpcap

Does someone know about a CPAN module on Win32 that captures network packets and edit them on the fly? As far as I know, the only Perl module on Win32 that deals with packets on the fly is [Net::Pcap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Pcap) but it only support passive monitoring and not affet the TCP/IP stack.

Is there a such module could someone provide example /reference /documentation ?

Comment: grap? Do you mean grab, or grep, or something else?

Comment: I think it's not posible to send raw packets in Win32 after WinXP SP2 patch.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842971/how-can-i-send-raw-ip-packets-with-perl-under-windows

Comment: Are you trying to edit packets inbound/outbound to/from your machine, or packages between two arbitrary hosts on a network?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, libpcap allows you to read copies of incoming and outgoing packets, and some implementations allow you to inject a raw packet, but not rewrite a packet. You would basically have to drop the original packet (something libpcap cannot do) and then inject a new one in it's place.

Firewall apps that allow you to filter incoming and outgoing packets might be able to do something like this. However, since you're talking about Perl and Win32 your options are probably limited.

Answer (score 0):

I think right answer is "implement proxy for this".

If it works in your scenario, try to implement proxy server. Listen on same port as your target service does and read all incoming traffic. If you need modification of packet, do it and pass all traffic to target service. Of course you have to implement both directions.

You can search for basic TCP deamon snippet in perl or maybe you can implement just module for existing proxy server for your service. Is it HTTP or what kind of traffic you need to handle?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Net::Pcap to capture traffic, then the Cygwin port of [TCPReplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/trac) to modify and replay the traffic. Obviously a Linux setup would be more reliable since TCPreplay would work on it out of the box without requiring cygwin.